# How do I properly configure compiz cube for gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, compiz

I see that compiz had an update. Is it possible to get cube rotation on ubuntu 18 with gnome 3? I have it installed with horizontal and vertical desktops at 4. I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Don't think Compiz is compatible with (standard) GNOME 3.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Shell 3 doesn't use Compiz.  It uses Wayland/Mutter instead.

But the good news is there are efforts to bring some of the eye-candy that Compiz offered.

[Wayfire](http://wayfire.org/) and the [Wayfire Config Manager (WCM)](https://github.com/WayfireWM/wcm) are an effort to bring the extremely useful functionality of the Compiz Configuration Settings Manager (CCSM) to Wayland.  It looks very promising.

Here is a YouTube playlist of all the Gnome Shell 3 [Compiz like Eye-Candy using the Wayfire Config Manager](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb7YRKEhWEBUIoT-a29UoJW9mhfzjpNle).  This video playlist was last updated Oct 2019 as of writing this.

The former chief developer of Compiz, Sam Spilsbury, is also working on a library to help bring about Compiz-like features to the Wayland desktop.  That project is the [libanimation](https://github.com/endlessm/libanimation) project.

Compiz brought some really good windows desktop management features that made working with the desktop much more efficient.  We don't need to get into those here....  and we're not talking about Wobbly windows or Desktop Cube.  Wobbly Windows and Cube are fun and all, but they are a little inefficient when you're trying to get things done quickly.  Nonetheless, Compiz brought features that made the desktop a snap, if you knew how to set it up.  Like binding your mouse "thumb" button to the thumbnail windows picker.  That is by far the fastest way to switch between windows.